# How to handle WCF Duplex in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

A little background:
I'm building a simple turn-based game. There is a server hosting WCF services and client built using `Xamarin.Forms` (with PCL libraries). So I wanted to built very simple "request-response" server with duplex channel - make a move and wait for response (catch the response/callback in the event). BUT...The problem is, I can't see netTcp binding or any duplex/dual bindings there. Only `BasicHttpBinding`.

My proxy PCL library targets:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- ASP.NET Core 1.0
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.iOS (Classic)

**My question is: How can I make an event based service architecture (a WCF Duplex communication with Callback) - so I could consume it in Xamarin.Forms?**

At this point tones of people probably want to downvote this question (or already done it), so I show what've done already:

I found ticket [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41392) and a lot of complains (there and in other places) that Xamarin is doing nothing about wcf duplex communication. This doesn't look promising. But maybe you have some good workaround this problem?

As for now, I have done it like this:

```
public async Task<MyResponse> Start(int id)
{
    MyResponse response;
    // doing stuff...
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => response);
}
```

so, I'm calling asynchronously a service and basically wait till it returns. Because it's async, the client's screen is not frozen. I'm not sure it's the best solution...

The best solution would be an event based architecture (using callbacks, since you have to wait for your opponent). But I have no idea how to do it? Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Comment: There is a discussion about it: [Could you guys let some of the team members go to update WCF of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS?](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1688)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF development has been suspended and resumed many times. I do not believe that you will see work done in this area given that REST services(Or frameworks built upon it like Service Stack) are the modern approach rather than WCF.

You can read a list of items that have no plan for support here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/#components-with-no-plan-to-support (The whole article gives more history into this as well)

As for your question, there are many ways to approach a turn-based game with modern services. A quick example might be using a framework built for this. `Xamarin.Android` has a turn-based multiplayer package they ship with Google Play Services to do this:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer (You can scroll down to the `Client Implementations` to support more than just Android)

There are also things like `SignalR` https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR in which you can create turn-based mechanisms with.

Finally you can also do the same with a REST service. However with a REST service, you won't be able to really capture the session state but you could model a turn based game in the sense of having enpoints such as:

`/game/<gameID>/turn/<turnID>`

Thus you can model a game and what the state of a player's turn is based on the `turnID`. It really depends on the complexity of your turn based game, but for simple things like Chess/Tic Tac Toe/Rock Paper Scissors, this is definitely possible.

In the example of waiting for turns, you can grab the latest turn and return which player's turn it is or something on those lines.

Comment: Thx, question.. when you said "REST", did you mean WCF's BasicHttpBinding? Like I showed in my example with async services? Or some ASP web services. I'm not familar what tech is the most modern today for restful services??

Comment: Also, I'd like to keep the same code for ios and android (i'm using xamarin.forms). I have separated pcl that is used by every xamarin.forms client. So, solution just for one platform is not good to me

Comment: @MarvinLaw Google's `Play Games Services` are available on `iOS` with native helper wrappers (https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/turnbasedMultiplayer), but all of Google's APIs are available via `Rest` apis (which all their "native" wrappers use) and can be used cross-platform (iOS, Android, Browser, Unity, ...) :  https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted

Comment: @SushiHangover What are advantages of `Google Play Services' over 'SingnalR' ? Those are two different ways

Comment: @MarvinLaw `SignalR` works great for relaying events|messages between connected clients but thats it. If your game needs player registrations, logins, leaderboards, player invites, matching, etc... you either write it yourself and run those services on public facing servers or turn to a game service, Google is one of those services... *Personally* I prefer to use a service to provide that infrastructure and framework when it fits the game/app requirements and instead focus on the "game/app" then *reinventing the wheel*....

Comment: @MarvinLaw I try to use Google and Apple infrastructures whenever i can as they have huge development teams providing gaming services to 100 millions of connected clients and maintain those API frameworks between major OS releases, guarantee infrastructure uptime, etc... , something a small game/app team will struggle to do and cause possible delays to a game release. Do you want to write/maintain a gaming framework, infrastructure, hosting costs, or write the game and release it to the App stores ... ;-) You will have to make that decision yourself based upon your app/game requirements.

Comment: @SushiHangover It's a simple 'tic-tac-toe' like game. It will not have any registrations, logins or leaderboards. It will be: game request -> waiting for another player -> found an opponent -> start a game. That's it. So . you would recommend me Google Play Service for that? Also, I don't need to implement a server at all (using Google Play Services) ?

Comment: @MarvinLaw With Google, they handle all the infrastructure ;-) Without some type of player queue (and related framework) how would you connect two users to a private `SignalR` channel, disconnect the loser, match the next player to the last winner, connect them to the SignalR channel, etc... ... Your 2 player "game" sounds like it is perfect for Google's Gaming services and I would use it... but again, you need to review what Google offers and make your own choice.

Comment: @SushiHangover that's one last question: Do you see somewhere in the mix, the solution I purposed in my question: basicHttpBinding with async services, which turns down to request->response, but non blocking. A little something like.. you subscribe to an event, but you can get one callback (technically.. a response). Of course with that solution I need to buy a host, implement the server and deploy it. But it's almost done already, so I was wondering how would you rate this particular solution. Although, I really like the idea with Google play services, so I will probably go that way anyway.

Comment: @MarvinLaw Your basicHttpBinding flow could be made to work, personally I find WCF very heavy (in memory&performance) for mobile devices and while the full WCF stack is very feature rich, personally I would implement SignalR/WebSockets for simple chat, ping / reply, client to client eventing, etc... communications. For "real-time" gaming interactions and eventing low level UDP/TCP sockets with your own servers (cloud/hosted/...) are used by most games today while also using higher level gaming frameworks (Google/Apple/custom) at the same time to provide the player matching, leaderboards, etc..